# How to isolate(seperate) Orders section in Wordpress WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Orders Section is located in Admin Panel which means that Order Manager has access to everything like Pages, Products, Settings etc. Is there a way to limit Manager Abilities?

Comment: Try  [**User Role editor**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) free plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use plugins available to increase/decrease user capabilities. ex. User Role Capabilities.